# java.lang.ClassCastException fetching a resultset using spring jdbc template after upgrade to JDK 1.7

Tags: java, spring, classcastexception

I am facing this exception while migrating to JDK1.7

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.rowset.providers.RIOptimisticProvider cannot be cast to
>   javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncProvider

while fetching a resultset using spring jdbc template.

Here is the example:

```
private String[] findDetailsByName(String name) {
    String[] retVal = null;

    SqlRowSet res = springJdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select * from table where param = (?)",
            new Object[] { name}); // ClassCast exception ocurring here
    while(res.next()){
        retVal = new String[2];
        retVal[0] = res.getString("COLUMN_1").trim();
        retVal[1] = res.getString("COLUMN_2").trim();
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

This same example method is working fine in JDK 1.6, But throwing ClassCastException while migrating to JDK1.7.

stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.rowset.providers.RIOptimisticProvider cannot be cast to javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncProvider
        at javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncFactory.getInstance(SyncFactory.java:605)
        at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.<init>(CachedRowSetImpl.java:360)
        at com.sun.rowset.RowSetFactoryImpl.createCachedRowSet(RowSetFactoryImpl.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeJdbcMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:224)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeJdbcMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:209)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.newCachedRowSet(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.createSqlRowSet(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:67)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.extractData(SqlRowSetResultSetExtractor.java:1)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(JdbcTemplate.java:805)
```

Comment: please put all the code in \``

Comment: @Kyle Luke, during my initial analysis for resolution I removed rowset-1.0.1-patched.jar from pom.xml and that resolved this error. this might be helpful for some one.

Comment: Better formatting, better title.

Comment: @Petter, I improved the question with an example  and with more details.

Comment: Ok prefect consider also to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing references of `rowset-1.0.1-patched.jar` from `pom.xml` resolved this error.